# Does itemprop have a different meaning on links vs. span tags?

Tags: html, url, microdata

I'm using Schema.org markup for a `Person`, but I get inconsistent results in Google's Rich Snippet Testing Tool when using an `<a>` tag vs. a `<span>` tag. Take these two examples:

```html
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="http://example.com/user/username">
    <span itemprop="name">username</span>
  </a>
</span>
```

```html
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <a href="http://example.com/user/username" itemprop="name">username</a>
</span>
```

The first one shows the name is parsed as `username`, but when I tried the second one to save on HTML, it shows the username is `http://example.com/user/username` - i.e. the URL of the link.

Why does this happen, and is it correct behaviour? I can't find any resources that make a distinction between `itemprop` on a link vs. a `span`.

Comment: And this is why I prefer to use JSON-LD.

Comment: @Simon why repeat all your content in a JSON block? It makes sense to me to use the existing HTML.

Comment: Because often writing your content around schema is not natural because more than often you start organising and displaying page content for  Google and Bing and not Visitors.  JSON-LD is easier to manage and does not suffer from having to work your UX around your code. Furthermore, JSON-LD can be added in Google Tag Manager making it even faster and saves your server having to serve this so called SAME CONTENT :)

Comment: That’s never happened to me. I add attributes to existing elements, occasionally add wrapper elements, but I’ve never needed to change the design or UX to accommodate Schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### What the spec says

Yes, that behaviour is correct. [Section 5.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#values) of the W3C Microdata spec describes which value gets used.

In most cases, the element’s content gets used as `itemprop` value, but in some cases, an attribute’s value gets used as `itemprop` value.

This is the case for these six attributes¹: `content`², `src`, `href`, `data`, `value`, `datetime`.

#### What this means in practice

If you want to use the content of an `a` element (instead of the URL in its `href` attribute) as property value, you have to use/add a suitable parent or child element:

```html
<a href="ignored-url"><span itemprop="property">property value</span></a>
```

```html
<span itemprop="property"><a href="ignored-url">property value</a></span>
```

If you want to provide a URL as property value, you must use `itemprop` on one of the [*URL property elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#dfn-url-property-elements) (i.e., elements that can³ have a `href`, `src`, or `data` attribute). So this would be invalid (unless you want to provide a string as value which just looks like a URL):

```html
<!-- INVALID --> <span itemprop="property">http://example.com/foo</span>
```

---

¹ It must be valid for the element to have this attribute. So for an (invalid!) `<div href="" itemprop=""></div>`, the element content gets used, not the `href` value.

² In WHATWG’s and W3C’s old spec of Microdata, [only the `meta` element can have the `content` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669), but the new W3C Microdata spec (currently a Working Draft) allows `content` on any element. If an element has a `content` attribute and also one of the other listed attributes, `content` gets used.

³ Microdata [makes it invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#content-models) to have one of the *URL property elements* without their respective URL attribute (i.e., `href`, `src`, `data`), except for the `link` element (but it’s already required by HTML to have the `href` attribute).

Comment: As always(!), Excellent! Cheers!!